# What is the lowest precentage KO possible?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

What is the lowest percentage knock out possible? I don't mean just removing a stock, but getting the red critical line across the screen and not giving the enemy time to try and recover.

Don't include counters because they tend to be too situational.

To attempt to make it easier to get a less broad answer, conisder it from the center of the stage  (person reciving hit at center, other where ever they must be) and not the edge of it. Also, it would be taking place on an Omega stage, the matchup though would be dependent on getting the best answer.

Comment: This would be different for every character.

Comment: Couldn't this be 1% by positioning the characters as close to the blast line as possible and dealing a 1% attack? It would give no possibility for recovery and might even produce the red critical line (even though you couldn't see it).

Comment: @ShadowZ. No tricks or anything!? You need to specify that more concretely in the question or there will be tricks and stuff. For example, KO'ing a light character on a platform that is currently rising toward the top of the screen (the top blast line) could significantly lower the percentage needed compared to any character standing in the exact center of the Final Destination stage.

Comment: Also, in your reverse Warlock punch example, wouldn't the percentage be 55% or so since the reverse Warlock punch itself deals 35%?

Comment: I added some claifications that should be able to make this less broad and give it a more definite answer.

Answer (score 2):

Almost impossible to tell and it's character specific.

Each stage has a different off-screen kill line. So it's stage specific as well.

The lightest character in the game is Jigglypuff. The strongest attack in the game is a fully charged home run bat attack.

If you use a home run bat against a Jigglypuff while standing on the edge of a almost any stage, it will KO her every time.

Comment: Ganondorf's reverse warlock punch is stronger than a home run.

Answer (score 1):

The "red critical line" you mention in the question is calculated based on the knockback about to be delivered combined with how far away the blast line in the impending direction is. So if you were to stand right against the blast line on a walk-off stage, pretty much any attack of nonzero knockback will cause both said effect and a KO at any percentage (including negative ones).

Now, given the edit made to the question stating this:

> conisder it from the center of the stage (person reciving hit at center, other where ever they must be) and not the edge of it. Also, it would be taking place on an Omega stage, the matchup though would be dependent on getting the best answer.

...the answer is still "far too many variables". What's the weight of the target? Is the attacker at high enough damage that the "rage effect" is amplifying their knockback? What's the angle of the hitbox? Should the target be DI'ing or SDI'ing to surivive, or to die faster? Are items like the Home-Run Bat, Dragoon, or Daybreak allowed? What about the Beetle or Boss Galaga? Do all Omega stages really have the same dimensions? (Some people suggest it's not the case.) Are you playing in Stamina mode and therefore at -150% damage (that's how the engine treats 150HP)?